# How to put a set of pgfkeys in... a pgfkey

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

I'd like to define a pgfkey that can contain some others pgfkeys, that I could give as input to another node.

Here is the MWE. The first function `myRectangle` works, but is not really practical. The second one is easier to read... but does not work:

```
% \RequirePackage{atbegshi}\AtBeginShipoutInit
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}
% Define the used keys in the following document
\pgfkeys{
  /myKeys/.is family, /myKeys,
  default/.style =
  {
    width  = 1cm,
    my tikz commands={},
  },
  width/.estore in = \kWidth,
  my tikz commands/.estore in = \kTikzCommands
}

% This work, but is dirty
\newcommand{\myRectangle}[1][]{%
  \pgfkeys{/myKeys, default, #1}%
  \edef\test{\noexpand\node [draw, minimum width=\kWidth, inner sep=0pt, shape=rectangle, very thick, color=red, minimum height=1cm, \kTikzCommands] at (current page.center) {};}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    \test %
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

% This does not work, and I'd like to make it work
\newcommand{\myRectangleB}[1][]{%
  \pgfkeys{/myKeys, default, #1}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    \node [draw, minimum width=\kWidth, inner sep=0pt, shape=rectangle, very thick, color=red, minimum height=1cm, \kTikzCommands] at (current page.center) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}


\begin{document}

% Ok
\myRectangle[width=10cm,my tikz commands={fill=blue, dashed}]
% No ok
\myRectangleB[width=10cm,my tikz commands={fill=blue, dashed}]

\end{document}
```

and here is the error:

```
ERROR: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/fill=blue, dashed' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

Any idea to make this more readable ?

Thank you.

Comment: that error also shows that your macro is not expanded and swallowed as a whole.

Comment: @percusse: That's why I did the strange thing above that works, but I tried to use expand after without success. But I'm not very good using expand after, so I may did a bad thing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using a style instead of a macro?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\pgfkeys{
  /myKeys/.is family, /myKeys/.cd,
  default/.style={
    width= 1cm,
    my tikz commands={},
  },
  width/.estore in=\kWidth,
  kTikzCommands/.style={},
  my tikz commands/.style={
    kTikzCommands/.style={#1}
  }
}
\newcommand{\myRectangleB}[1][]{%
  \pgfkeys{/myKeys, default, #1}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    \node [draw, minimum width=\kWidth, inner sep=0pt, 
      shape=rectangle, very thick, color=red, minimum height=1cm, 
        /myKeys/kTikzCommands/.try] at (current page.center) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\myRectangleB[width=10cm,my tikz commands={fill=blue, dashed}]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed it works, thank you very much ! Just a question, do I really need to use two keys for that ? (here kTikzCommands and my tikz commands) I tried to remove kTikzCommands, but then I've errors like "ERROR: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/myKeys/fill', to which you passed 'blue', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.". I also tried to use "/tikz/.cd" at the beginning of my tikz commands, but then it also changes the keys inside myKeys...

Comment: You can use one key if you use the `.style` handler all the time, for example, `my tikz commands/.style={}` or `my tikz commands/.style={fill=blue, dashed}`. Then `/myKeys/my tikz commands/.try` should work fine in the node.

Comment: Hum interesting... I thought that `my tikz commands={...}` was more or less equivalent to `my tikz commands/.style={...}`. Thank you !